# External variable in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a script, in which a script snippet is:

```
x=3
awk '$2=$x{print $1}' infile
```

The external variable is `x`,

but it prompts an error in `awk`

So in this situation, how to make `awk` run successfully?

Comment: in the future, please include exact error output, formatted using {} tool at top of edit box. Also, do you mean $2=$x? that would assign the value of $x to the $2 variable in each line. You probably want to compare $2 with x value, so use `$2 == x`. Good luck.

Answer (score 30):

You pass an external variable for use in `awk` with the `-v` option:

```
some_variable=3
awk -v x=$some_variable '$2 == x {print $1}' infile
```

Also note that you need to change your code from `$2=$x` to `$2 == x`

- Use `==` instead `=`: the latter is assignment
- Do not prefix normal variables with `$` inside the `awk` script.

Aside: You need to specify one `-v` for each variable you want to pass in, e.g:

```
var1=2
var2=4
awk -v x=$var1 -v y=$var2 '$2 == x {print y " " $1}' infile
```

Comment: Note that you do not actually need to use `-v` at all.  `awk '$2 == x' x=3` is exactly the same as `awk -v x=3 '$2 == x'`

Comment: Well, not EXACTLY the same. The former won't allow you to add a BEGIN section where you need to access the variable and the latter won't allow you to change initial values of your variable between files. IMHO using -v is usually what you want.

Comment: this was the only answer that worked for me.  thank you.

Answer (score 9):

`awk` has a `-v` option for this purpose, or as @nevelis mentions, just use double quotes:

```
awk -v x=3 ' $2==x {print $1} '
```

Answer (score 2):

GAWK also supports the following syntax:

```
awk '$2 == x {print $1}' x=3 infile
```

An interesting usage is:

```
awk '$2 == x {print $1}' x=3 infile1 x=10 infile2
```

in this case `x` will be equal to `3` for `infile1` and equal to `10` for `infile2`

Answer (score 1):

```
set -a    
x=3
awk '$2==ENVIRON["x"]{print $1}' infile
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "" - bash won't substitute single quotes.

Eg:

> x=3 awk "\$2=$x{print \$1}" infile

Comment: That rapidly gets nasty if there are many shell metacharacters in the `awk` script, and there usually are some.

Comment: Do NOT do this, it will produce many nasty side effects depending on your variable settings.

Comment: Agreeing with the hereinabove comments, I could remark, that such substitution method does not allow (or at least make this very complicated) to use prearranged scripts (through `-f` option).

Comment: Fair comments, I was pointing out the reason the OPs snippet wasn't working was that bash wasn't substituting because of the single quotes, but I provided a poor example.